# Weather app: button doesn't show any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to create a simple Weather app using openweathermap.org using ajax and I can't seem to return my data when I press the button I created. The console doesn't show me any errors and I can't figure out where I made a mistake or what I am missing.

`Here is my code and what I have tried: https://jsfiddle.net/AdelinaLipsa/kyzmao9n/`

I want the button next to my input to return the selected city temperature(for the moment). Where did I make a mistake? Thank you for your help.

Comment: check the dev tools (F12 in chrome), the website seems to be blocking http requests for the jquery link and weather API request, when attempting to change the links to https this now loads the data, however the page does not appear to display it, you may need to make an additional code change

Comment: I tried in chrome and it doesn't show any errors, and the button is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle currently blocks insecure requests over HTTP

- change your jquery import to https
- change your api request $.ajax call to https

One code issue:

- fix a typo on your $.ajax call `succes` to `success`, the callback was never being called as it was incorrectly named

example fiddle with weather now populated: https://jsfiddle.net/3vdx98go/1/

Comment: the typo was the issue. shame on me. thank you for pointing it out!